# Is every plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ a line in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, almost-complex

Every complex line, that is, one-dimensional complex affine space, in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a real plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is the converse true? That is, is every real plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ a complex line in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: There are real plane in $\mathbb R^4$ what is not complex: you need those plane $L$ which satisfies $\sqrt{-1} L = L$.

Comment: @Arctic Char: I doubt the OP is asking about complex lines containing (0,0); A complex line $L\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ is affine, and satisfies $$aw+bz+c=0$$ for all $(w,z)\in L$ and some complex constants $a,b,c$. For that every plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can indeed be realized as a complex line in $\mathbb{C}^4$. What you suggested are the lines containing the origin, that is those for which $c=0$.

Comment: I am not sure why you have $\mathbb C^4$ here? @JackLeGrüß

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo error. I meant every plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be realized as a complex line in $\mathbb{C}^2$ once you identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$ by the canonical map $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto ((x_1+ix_2),(x_3+ix_4))\,.$$

Comment: Then I guess the fact about complex affine spaces that corresponds to what @ArcticChar said would be: the complex affine subspaces are exactly the real affine subspaces which are also closed under affine combinations of the form $(1-i)a + ib$.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß I don't think every plane (affine or not) in $\mathbb R^4$ can be realized as a complex affine line in $\mathbb C^2$ (under that identification). The answer below is precisely showing that.

Comment: An example is instructive here. Under the identification $(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1)\mapsto (x_0+iy_0,x_1+iy_1)$, consider the planes $\Pi_1=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$ and $\Pi_2=\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$. Over $\Bbb C$, $\Pi_1$ is clearly a line generated by $(1,0)$ and $\Pi_2$ is a plane generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ElliotG Since we're talking about affine spaces here, I suppose you're talking about $\Pi_1$ being the "affine hull" of $\{ (0,0,0,0), (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0) \}$ and $\Pi_2$ being the "affine hull" of $\{ (0,0,0,0), (1,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0) \}$?  (Though to be honest, I don't know whether "affine hull" by analogy with "convex hull", or "affine span" by analogy with "linear span", would be more commonly used.)

Comment: @Artic Char: Ah, you’re right about the identification; for that canonical one, no, quasi’s example is not realizable (but it is when the canonical 1st and 3rd axes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are identified with the respective real parts in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Perhaps I should put my thoughts carefully in a answer.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Regardless, linear subspaces are affine subspaces, so this still shows the statement fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the set
$$
A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R}^4{\,\mid\,}x_1=x_2\;\text{and}\;x_3=x_4\}
$$
Then $A$ is a real plane through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Suppose $A$ is also a complex line through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the identification 
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\;{\small{\longleftrightarrow}}\;(x_1+x_2i,x_3+x_4i)=(z_1,z_2)$$

Then for some $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, not both zero, we would have
$$
A=\{(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2{\,\mid\,}az_1+bz_2=0\}
$$
But then from $(0,0,1,1)\in A$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ we would get $b=0$, and from $(1,1,0,0)\in A$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ we would get $a=0$, contradiction.

Comment: Are you assuming $z_1 = x_1 + \sqrt {-1}x_2$? It is not clear how your $\mathbb R^4$ is identified with $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: Yes. Should I not assume that?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (note that some uses $z_1 = x_1 + i x_3$ and $z_2 = x_2 + ix_4$ and if that's the case your $A$ is actually $\{z_1 = z_2\}$ in \mathbb C^2$).

Comment: Right, but once the identification is fixed, we can get an analogous counterexample.

Comment: @Quasi: yes, an analogous counterexample can be found; but perhaps that’s where my thinking about the problem diverges; indeed, if the canonical identification (and perhaps any generic one) is made, then apparently, the one to one correspondence between the planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $ \mathbb{C}^2$ fails.